# Query date instead of datetime docdb

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am using docdb. I would like to query the processTime with **date** only instead of datetime. My input pdate = 26-09-2017 which is dateonly. I am using cast function to convert datetime to date in sql query but I am getting syntax error. I am doing this in **c#**. Using **LINQ** for query

I have the following json in document db.

```
[{
 "processTime": "2017-09-26T21:05:28.7954106+05:30",
 "submittedBy": "671"
}
{
 "processTime": "2017-09-26T21:05:28.7954106+05:30",
 "submittedBy": "679"
}
{
 "processTime": "2017-09-26T21:05:28.7954106+05:30",
 "submittedBy": "679"
}
]
```

I am querying the db as follows

```
            new SqlQuerySpec()
            {
                QueryText = "SELECT * FROM cols e WHERE e.submittedBy = @ci AND CAST( e.processTime AS int) = @date",
                Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                {
                new SqlParameter("@ci",  cid.ToString()),
                new SqlParameter("@date", pdate)
                }
            }, DefaultOptions);
```

I am getting syntax error near CAST function

```
{"Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":61,\"end\":65},\"code\":\"SC1001\",\"message\":\"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.\"}]}\r\nActivityId: 5661ff3b-64cb-46d7-8c9e-0125145a8fb3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nacho's answer looks like it will work. However, the beauty of the ISO-8601 format is that you can also just do string comparisons. So the SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM cols e WHERE e.submittedBy = @ci AND STARTSWITH( e.processTime, @dateString)
```

@dateString should be a string in the format like "2017-10-20".

Note, you can also do date ranges this way and as long as there is a range index on the submittedBy field by using the inequality operators > and <=. Note however, that the second date in the range is exclusive, while the first one is inclusive.

I also notice that you use ISO-8601 strings with timeshift format. That's fine as long as you can be sure the data for any single query always has the same shift. However, if you want more control over it, store it in zulu time (GMT) and do the shifting at query time by adjusting the string literals at query time. I've written up this approach in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/lmaccherone/5371881) and the tzTime and Lumenize libraries mentioned in that writeup were built to facilitate that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DATE() function to get only the day of the processTime column like this:

```
        new SqlQuerySpec()
        {
            QueryText = "SELECT * FROM cols e WHERE e.submittedBy = @ci AND DATE( e.processTime) = STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%d-%m-%Y')",
            Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
            {
            new SqlParameter("@ci",  cid.ToString()),
            new SqlParameter("@date", pdate)
            }
        }, DefaultOptions);
```

You need to convert your pdate value from dd-mm-aaaa to aaaa-mm-dd with

```
STR_TO_DATE(pdate,'%Y-%m-%d')
```